# Animation clash

Tags: html, css

I've worked out to attach two different animations to the same element, by using a comma, but the animation is finding compromise instead of executing each in successive order. How do I get one to execute and then the next when it's finished? What I want is right to left and, when finished, top to bottom. what I have is diagonal. Why?

```css
    .contact{
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border: 50px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 70px solid red;
      position: relative;
      top: -50px;
    }
    .contact:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      left: -50px;
      top: 70px;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border: 50px solid 
    transparent;
      border-top: 70px solid 
      red;
    }

    .contact{
      margin-left: 200px; 
      top: 20px; transform: 
      rotate(90deg);
    }

    .contact {
      animation: fish 4s linear 
      infinite, fish1 4s linear 
      infinite; animation-
      duration: 4s; animation-iteration- 
      count: infinite; animation.   
      direction: alternate;   
      animation-timing-function: linear;
    } 

    @keyframes fish {
      from {right: 100px;} to {right: 1px; position: relative;} 
    }

    @keyframes fish1 {
      from {top: 2px;} to {top: 200px;} 
    }
```

```html
<div class="contact"></div>
```

Comment: both will run at the same time, if you want one after another use them inside the same animation and split your keyframes

Comment: OK. Example please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```css
.contact{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid red;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: 0; 
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  float:right;
}
.contact:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 70px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 70px solid red;
}

.contact {
  animation: fish 4s linear infinite; 
} 

@keyframes fish {
  0%   {right: 0px; top: 0px;}
  25%  {right: 200px; top: 0px;}
  50%  {right: 200px; top: 200px;}
  75%  {right: 0px; top: 200px;}
  100% {right: 0px; top: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="contact"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Animation Keyframes**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/), simply add a percentage for each keyframe. Also there is no need to declare multiple classes `.contact`, I've merged them into one

```css
.contact{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px solid red;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 200px; 
  top: 20px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);

  animation: fish 4s linear infinite;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;   
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.contact:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: 70px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top: 70px solid 
  red;
}

@keyframes fish {
  0% { right: 100px; }
  50% { right: 1px; top: 2px; }
  100% { top: 200px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="contact"></div>
```